# Passport authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have to authenticate user with passport tpe authentication. for that i set the following configuration in web.config.

```
<identity userName="username" password="password" impersonate="true"/>

<authentication mode="Passport">
            <passport redirectUrl="https://login.yahoo.com"/>
        </authentication>
```

Please confirm if this is correct/complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />
        <authentication mode="Passport">
            <passport redirectUrl="login.aspx" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" /> <!-- Allow all users -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="attendees">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

i recommend you pls take a look at this [authentication using passport mode](http://codeidol.com/asp/c-sharp-asp-xml-ado.net/Security/Passport-Authentication/)